# Descrição Completa para um flag em uma Lista/Ienumerable em C# Asp Net MVC

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

Tenho uma lista de registros, 
onde tenho um Status (STS_BANCO) com valores (A de Ativo e I de Inativo, P aguardando aprovação,e N analise, entre outros ) onde na tabela gravei "A,I,N,P" , 
E também tenho uma tabela que chamo de List, onde gravo o flg A e a Descrição Ativo e todas as outras Descrições completas, 
porem gostaria que ele me mostrasse o Ativo ou Inativo e os outros, com a descrição completa na lista.
Eu Utilizo o a formatação de Grid.

Segue código abaixo.

```
@model IEnumerable<PadraoMVC.Models.BANCO>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Banco - Listar";
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 10, canSort: true, canPage: true);
}

<body>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <br />

    <h2>Listagem de Bancos Cadastrados </h2>
    <br />

@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle:"gridtable",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns:
    grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("IDE_BANCO", "ID"),
    grid.Column("NUM_BANCO", "Banco"),
    grid.Column("DES_BANCO", "Descrição"),
    grid.Column("STS_BANCO", "Status"),
    //aqui ele mostra A por exemplo, gostaria de Mostrar "Ativo"
    grid.Column("DAT_INCLUSAO", "Data Inclusão"),
    grid.Column("NOM_LOGIN_INCLUSAO", "Responsável"),
    grid.Column("DAT_ALTERACAO", "Data Alteração"),
    grid.Column("NOM_LOGIN_ALTERACAO", "Responsável Alteração"),
    grid.Column("NUM_IP_INCLUSAO", "IP Inclusão"),
    grid.Column(format: @<div>
        <a href="EditarBanco/@item.IDE_BANCO">Editar</a><br />
        <a href="ExcluirBanco/@item.IDE_BANCO">Excluir</a>
    </div>) ),
            firstText: "Primeiro",
            previousText: "Anterior",
            nextText: "Proximo",
            lastText: "Ultimo",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All
            )
        <br />

        @Html.Hidden("dir", grid.SortDirection)
        @Html.Hidden("col", grid.SortColumn) 

    <ul class="optul">
        <li class="optli">
            @Html.ActionLink("Voltar","Index", "Banco")
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br /><br /><br />
</body>
```

Comment: Não relacionado à pergunta, mas creio que não estejam corretas as tags `meta` dentro do `body`. Elas deveriam estar em `head`.